# Automate file transfer to a windows server

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, file-management, file-transfer

I'm looking for a simple way to copy files over internet to a remote server using a tool that would work in the commant line, for automation purposes. So no RDP.

All I've come up is FTP. Are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For file transfers over the internet, your best option is [scp/sftp](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html).

- Easily automated
- Authentication, encryption
- Widely adopted

The destination server will need to be running an sshd server, such as OpenSSH. The source will need the scp/sftp client (also provided by OpenSSH). Most linux distros include these by default.

On Windows, these packages can be installed using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/).